# How to put badge at the right corner of a view

Tags: android, badge

I am trying a badge View as [suggested in this link](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger). I am trying with this code .

```
String count_str = Integer.toString(count);
            TextView text_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            badge1 = new BadgeView(this, text_view);
            badge1.setText(count_str);  
            badge1.show();
```

But the badge is appearing in the middle of the TextView. How can I put this badge in the right corner of the TextView?

[image]

Comment: Is the parent container a RelativeLayout? `Badging views inside RelativeLayout with dependencies may break alignment`

Comment: parent container is LinearLayout .

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code for [`DemoActivity`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger/blob/master/src/viewbadger/demo/DemoActivity.java) in this library, it appears the following method is responsible for the position of the badge:

```
 badge1.setBadgePosition(BadgeView.POSITION_CENTER);
```

**Edit**

And the following options from the `BadgeView` class:

```
public static final int POSITION_TOP_LEFT = 1;
public static final int POSITION_TOP_RIGHT = 2;
public static final int POSITION_BOTTOM_LEFT = 3;
public static final int POSITION_BOTTOM_RIGHT = 4;
public static final int POSITION_CENTER = 5;
```

Comment: I want to put this badge at the right of textview . What can I do this ?

Comment: @osimerpothe Use one of the constants above, i.e. `setBadgePosition(BadgeView.POSITION_TOP_RIGHT);`

Comment: Using setBadgePosition(BadgeView.POSITION_TOP_RIGHT); the badge does not appear in the right of textview .

Comment: @osimerpothe Take a look at Frank N Stein's comment on your original post. In the [ReadMe](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger/blob/master/README.markdown) file for this library it states limitations, one of which is that a `RelativeLayout` may break alignment.

Comment: But the parent container is LinearLayout

Comment: @osimerpothe Is your `TextView` `width` attribute set to `match_parent`? Chance are there's some padding involved that's pushing it closer to the centre if you use `wrap_content`